# sql server date difference when only month and year mentioned

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datediff, sql-date-functions

Given the 2 months and years. NO day mentioned. I need to calculate the difference between those two dates in SQL.Example of the columns in  SQL server DB.

```
MonthFROM    YearFROM   MonthTo  YearTO

12           2010       1        2012
```

Output should be 14 months.

Comment: Those aren't dates. So what result are you actually looking for?

Comment: @AaronBertrand. No they are not dates. Just 4 columns of types integers with months and years. Wish to get the output between those as 14 months

Comment: Actually, Jan 2012 would be 13 months after Dec 2010, not 14 as you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f80e/10/0) of the following:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),
                 CAST(MonthFROM as varchar) + '/01/' + CAST(YearFROM as varchar),
                 101), 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), 
                 CAST(MonthTo as varchar) + '/01/' + CAST(YearTO as varchar), 
                 101)) + 1 AS MonthPast
FROM MyTable;
```

The result would be:

```
MONTHPAST
14
```

The actual months difference is `13` but you had `14` as what you are expecting as a result.  If your calculation was wrong and you indeed need `13` then remove the `+ 1` from the query.

Answer (score 2):

It is not good idea to keep date in this manner.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, CAST(YearFROM as varchar) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(MonthFROM as varchar), 2) + '01',
                      CAST(YearTO as varchar) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(MonthTO as varchar), 2) + '01')
```

Comment: .The customer stores just the month and year the contract is valid for.i.e he mentions june 2010 to sept 2012. That is why i am storing the month and year only. Also while using your query I get this error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." All the 4 columns are integers.

Comment: That means that you have an incorrect data in your columns, for instance, the value 13 in MonthFROM.

Comment: @RookieAppler Hamlet's code is ok. If I were you I'd put a CHECK CONSTRAINT on all month columns to avoid problems.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following using simple arithmetic:

```
Select (YearTo - YearFrom) * 12 + MonthTo - MonthFrom + 1 as Difference
  from MyTable;
```

Comment: I think you don't have to add +1 to month, if from and to year and month are same then also it will give a difference.. check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/770d1/2

Comment: I added +1 to month based on the user info that from 2010/12 to 2012/1 there are 14 months as per his requirements.

Comment: It really depends on what he is doing with the result.  There isn't enough information on the question to determine that 14 is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012
here is the quick way to do this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, DATEFROMPARTS (YearFROM, MonthFROM, 01),
                DATEFROMPARTS (YearTO, MonthTo, 01))
FROM YourTable
```

Demo on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/492e5/4)

Comment: Note that your code returns 13 instead of 14 for the dates specified in the question.  You probably need to add +1 to meet the user's requirement.